# Rails 3 ArgumentError: Unknown key: begin_date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `Waiver` object that has_many memberships. I want to figure out if a waiver has a membership for a given quarter:

```
def has_current_membership?
  memberships.count("begin_date >= :begin_date AND end_date <= :end_date", { :begin_date => Time.now.beginning_of_quarter, :end_date => Time.now.end_of_quarter }).count > 0
end
```

This however gives me `ArgumentError: Unknown key: begin_date`. Membership does however have a begin_date column because if I do `Waiver.first.memberships` in the console I get:

```
[#<Membership id: 20, waiver_id: 1, begin_date: "2011-10-01", end_date: "2012-01-01", created_at: "2011-11-19 07:10:10", updated_at: "2011-11-19 07:10:10">]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `.where` for the find condition, instead of `.count` twice:

```
memberships.where("begin_date >= :begin_date AND end_date <= :end_date", { :begin_date => Time.now.beginning_of_quarter, :end_date => Time.now.end_of_quarter }).count > 0
```